# FullCalendar Turn off / hiding grid lines

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and I am loving it, however I would like to hide the grid lines in month view so that instead of cells it's more open. Is there a way to do this? I want it to look like this
[Calendar without grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUg1v.png)

I have tried manipulating the css but I'm not having much success since I'm new to it. Can someone please help.

Comment: Which grid lines? In which view? Which version of fullCalendar? Have you tried anything so far (e.g. with CSS rules)?

Comment: P.S. As you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) 
I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.